# which is the best payment gateway for service purchasing in iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, payment-gateway

I am developing one application for iOS. In that user can purchase doctor services. I dont have any idea about payment gateways. So, please suggest me which is the best payment gateway method and how to implement that in my iOS app. ( I am from India), i heard payment gateway methods depends upon the country.

Comment: Not really a programming question sir and did you do a Google search for: stackoverflow ios payment gateway ? because I sure got a lot of hits on them.

Comment: Zhang, thanks for your quick reply, i have searched google, but i got some of the methods, so for that i am confusing which is best to use. Hence i posted my query over here. Thanks for your valuable reply!

Comment: That's kinda subjective. There are good ones like Stripe and such, but they don't necessary support your country, or the business requirements of your app. Do you want users to pay using a physical credit card swiping like paypal pay pass, or get user to scan their card using card.io, or maybe go through a REST service? Or do they pay in advance using point system where they reload points with real money on a website.

Answer (score 9):

There are quite a few - also depends on your country as not all providers cover all countries. Take a look at:

https://stripe.com/

https://www.braintreepayments.com/

and probably http://www.paypal.com

What you want is something that's easy to code for (securely) in iOS. All the above (as well as many others) have APIs and sample code that make connecting to process payments easy and secure.

EDIT

Just seen you've added that you're in India. Assuming that means that you want to process payments in India, then I think your options (as at July 2014) are more limited. Certainly stripe and braintree don't cover India. I believe PayPal do (although maybe not with their latest APIs), so that might be your best bet.