# Xamarin Adyen or PayPal Integration

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm currently creating a content management system app for a company which requires the user to make a payment using a payment service.
I'm wondering if the google play store will allow us to submit an app with a PSP such as either of these two? If so, how would I go about doing this as I would need to retrieve the response from the PayPal payment in a web browser?

I appreciate any information given.

Comment: Refer to : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/android-dev/overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to what is allowed for app store and play store, there are existing questions covering both.

IOS: [which is the best payment gateway for service purchasing in iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930200/which-is-the-best-payment-gateway-for-service-purchasing-in-ios-app)

Andoid: [Android in app billing using external payment processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670487/android-in-app-billing-using-external-payment-processor)

For the actual processing of payments on these platforms, [Adyen's Checkout solution](https://docs.adyen.com/developers/in-app-integration) has SDK for both ios and android. Additionally, you can process paypal through Adyen as well.

Disclaimer: I work for Adyen.